# How come this c server isn't able to consume data sent with c client and get stuck on read system call?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

This is the client :

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define PORT 1026
#define SA struct sockaddr

int main(){


int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;
//CREATE SOCKET
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
   
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

if (connect(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != 0) {
        printf("connection with the server failed...\n");
        //exit(0);
    }

char buffw[]="Hello World";
int res;

res=write(sockfd,buffw,sizeof(buffw));

char buffr[10];
while( (read(sockfd,buffr,sizeof(buffr))) > 0 );
close(sockfd);

return 0;

}
```

And here is the server :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define SA struct sockaddr
#define PORT 1026


int main(){


 int sockfd, connfd;
 unsigned int len;
 struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;

//SOCKET CREATION
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
if (sockfd == -1) {
        printf("socket creation failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }

bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr =htonl(INADDR_ANY);
servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
//BIND
if ((bind(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) != 0) {
        printf("socket bind failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }
//LISTEN
if ((listen(sockfd, 5)) != 0) {
        printf("Listen failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }

for(;;){

len = sizeof(cli);

connfd = accept(sockfd, (SA*)&cli, &len);


if (connfd < 0) {
        printf("server accept failed...\n");
        exit(0);
    }else{
        printf("New connection accepted !\n");
    }
char buff;

//The read get stuck here without reading !!

while( ((buff=read(connfd,&buff,1))) > 0 ){
    printf("%c",buff);
};

close(connfd);
}


return 0;

}
```

I examined the traffic with wireshark and the TCP protocol stack receives properly 12 Bytes of data ("Hello World"). However it seems the read function get stuck. This doesn't happen if for example I turn the write function inside the client into a loop :

```
while ( (write(sockfd,buffw,sizeof(buffw))) > 0 ) ;
```

In this case the server keeps receiving the 12 Bytes infinitely.

Anyone knows the reason why read is behaving like that ? Moreover If I try to send data from a browser it works correctly. I just don't understand why is not working...

Comment: `buff=read(connfd,&buff,1)` - you are using `buff` both as the `ssize_t` size result of `read` and as the `&char` where the read data are written too. This makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your client is sending 12 bytes (11 characters + null terminator), then reading whatever the server sends something, which is nothing. So the client is stuck on `read()` after sending and does not close the connection.

The server is reading from the client 1 byte at a time in a loop until the client disconnects, which doesn't happen. After 12 bytes have been read, there are no more bytes to read, so `read()` waits for new bytes to arrive, which will never happen.

So, you end up in a deadlock situation where the client is waiting on the server, and the server is waiting on the client. You will have to kill one of the programs, or disable the network adapter, to end the deadlock.

Since the client is sending the string's null terminator, you can have the server look for that terminator and break its reading loop once it arrives, eg:

```
while( read(connfd, &buff, 1) > 0 ){
    printf("%c", buff);
    write(connfd, &buff, 1);
    if (buff == '\0') break;
}
```

Comment: I'm perfectly aware of the deadlock situation. I did it on purpose for some testing. The problem here is that my server isn't able to print anything despite the fact the 12 Bytes are (according to wireshark) correctly sent to the application by TCP @Remy Lebeau

Comment: @Kode1000 do you have the same problem if you use `recv()` instead of `read()` (and `send()` instead of `write()`)?

Comment: When I run the programs on my Mac, I see that the server reads all 12 bytes sent from the client (1 byte at a time), and then calls `read()` again, and `read()` blocks waiting for more input, which the client never sends because the client is blocked in `read()`.  The server calls `printf("%c", buff);` as expected, but the printed characters aren't shown in the Terminal window because `stdout` only flushes characters to its output when a newline is printed, or if you explicitly call `fflush(stdout)`

Comment: Did it print the characters when you run the server on your Mac ? Could you show me in more details the code you used ? I don't know but this behaviour of read is not convincing me... For example today I tried it again and it worked but only two times... I'm puzzled  @Jeremy Friesner

Comment: @Kode1000 Jeremy described the exact same behavior I did. And why the code you showed doesn't print the characters it does receive. Did you add flushing to your code?

Comment: @Kode1000 I ran the code you posted, more or less verbatim.  Try replacing `printf("%c", buff);` with `printf("received char [%c]\n", buff);` instead if you want easier-to-understand output